# How to properly tag a question about a subject that has subgroups that also have tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

The inspiration for this question comes from the boost libraries where boost itself has a tag, and, almost, every library within boost has a tag. So, when I'm (re)tagging a question that involves one of these dependent tags, do I also add the parent tag in addition to the dependent specific tag? With only 5 tags allowed, adding the parent tag restricts the ability to classify these questions, and yet without it, the question can't be found by simply selecting the parent tag. Also, if it is recommended to include the parent tag, how deep do you go?  For instance, [boost.spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-spirit) has two subgroup tags itself: [qi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-spirit-qi) and [karma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-spirit-karma).

I'm looking for guidance on what is the "proper" thing to do here, to add the parent tag or not? Although, it does suggest that we may want a tag hierarchy so that tagging with a dependent tag automatically implies the parent(s).  But, that may be more work than it is worth.

Comment: Surely this question has been asked before on MSO. If not, I'm flabberghasted.

Comment: likely, but I couldn't find it in my admittedly lackluster search for it.

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure to include the highest level (so that people browsing boost questions will see it) and the lowest level (so that searches will turn it up and experts in the field can see what the question pertains to).

After that you could include the libraries that are in between, but I would suggest only doing that if it makes sense by possibly adding value.

Comment: The trouble is sometimes there are a lot of applicable tags, and you can't include both the highest and lowest levels without going over the 5 tag limit.

Comment: @Robin, the highest and the lowest would be two tags.  After that you have 3 tag spaces remaining that you can fill in the middle levels if desired or used them for other details.

Comment: my concern with doing just that is shown by this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4810026/198315), in particular.  Obviously the networking tag is the weak one, but if it was stronger, which one would I then remove to tag it "boost-asio"?  I suspect that this situation is not all that uncommon.

Comment: @Rcollyer, not that familiar with boost-asio.  But asio seems like it just just be a tag synonym of boost-asio.

Comment: looking through it, you're likely right, asio is a synonym of boost-asio. For now, I'll concede the point as I can't find an immediate example where the 5 tag limit would prevent the double tagging.