# Tag Synonym Request: [asio]->[boost-asio]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, retag-request

As was pointed out by [JDK](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87852/how-to-properly-tag-a-question-about-a-subject-that-has-subgroups-that-also-have/87856#87856) in the comments of another question, all of the 95 questions tagged [asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asio) deal directly with [boost-asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-asio). 52 of which, are tagged with [both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-asio+asio). Of which, only 37 of which are [tagged with boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost+asio+boost-asio), also. This implies that there are 37 tags tagged with [boost and asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost+asio), but not boost-asio, although that is the clear intent. This seems a natural case for a synonym.

Comment: I'm in favour of retagging the questions, but allow asio to be its own tag. What if someone needs help because [ASIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Security_Intelligence_Organisation) has hacked into their computer?